# fs.writefile with an object returns [object object]

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, express, fs

I am trying to move data from a form to a json file, this is my first time doing something like this. When it runs, my json file looks like this:

[object Object] instead of displaying an email, username, and password.

This is my server code(expressjs):

```
app.post('/action_page.php',function(req,res){
    'use strict'
   email = req.body.email;
   username = req.body.name;
   password = req.body.password;

loginData = {
        email: email,
        username: username,
        password: password
    };

fs.writeFile('data.json', loginData, finished);

res.sendFile(__dirname + '/signupResponse.html');
```

email, username, and password are global variables declared as empty strings, and logindata is also global declared as such:

```
var loginData = {"email": "","username": "","password": ""};
```

Any help would be greatly apreciated!

Comment: as it is, `loginData` is a javascript object in memory. It needs to be converted in order to be serializable (saved). User `JSON.stringify(loginData)`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That problem can be resolved by using the `JSON.stringify` method to serialise the `loginData` object to a string which is what `fs.writeFile` expects for the second parameter.

You can do this by updating the following line like so:

```
fs.writeFile('data.json', JSON.stringify(loginData), finished);
```

Hope that helps!